# Passing data between Python and C# without writing a file

Tags: c#, python, stdout, stdin, inter-process-communicat

I would like to pass binary information between Python and C#. I would assume that you can open a standard in/out channel and read and write to that like a file, but there are a lot of moving parts, and I don't know C# too well. I want to do this sort of thing, but without writing a file.

```
# python code
with open(DATA_PIPE_FILE_PATH, 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(blob)
subprocess.Popen(C_SHARP_EXECUTABLE_FILE_PATH)
with open(DATA_PIPE_FILE_PATH, 'rb') as fid:
    'Do stuff with the data'

// C# code
static int Main(string[] args){
    byte[] binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(DataPipeFilePath);
    byte[] outputData;
    // Create outputData
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputData)
```

I've tried several different ways of using standard in/out, but I've had no luck matching them up, like I said, there are a lot of moving parts. I've tried things like

```
p = subprocess.Popen(C_SHARP_EXECUTABLE_FILE_PATH, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(blob)
p.stdin.close()
```

or

```
p = subprocess.Popen(C_SHARP_EXECUTABLE_FILE_PATH, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(blob)
```

on the python side along with

```
TextReader tIn = Console.In;
TextWriter tOut = Console.Out;
String str = tIn.ReadToEnd();
//etc...
```

as well as a couple of other things that didn't work on the C# side. I've had mild success with some things, but I've changed it around so much that I don't remember what has worked for what. Could somebody give me a hint as to which pieces would work the best, or if this is even possible?

The data I want to pass has null and other non-printable characters.

Comment: why not just use python.NET? depending on what you are doing, it works pretty well...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7367976

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: What is python.net?

Comment: see reed's answer below (we posted nearly at the same time), since he has a link there. it lets you access C# libraries in a way that is nearly native - you can even import a C# library in the console, and do some interactive tab completion, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This python code was correct

```
p = Popen(C_SHARP_EXECUTABLE_FILE_PATH, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(blob)
```

And on the C# side, I got it to work with

```
Stream ms = Console.OpenStandardInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use something like [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/), which provides interop directly between C# and (standard, C) Python.

Depending on what your Python routines need to do, [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) can also be a good option, as this is directly consumable and usable from within C#.

Both of these options avoid trying to communicate through the command line, as you have direct access to the Python objects from .NET, and vice versa.

Comment: I get the same error as described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633695/how-to-install-python-for-net-on-windows

Comment: make sure you match the python.NET version you are installing, with the version of python you have - mixing the two can cause weird errors like that.

Comment: @horriblyUnpythonic The versioning with python/python for .NET is typically the main issue.