# Pythonnet error: dynamic module not initialized properly

Tags: python, .net, python.net

I have Windows 7 x64 and a Python version 2.7.6 on win32.
The framework installed are:

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack.
So, when I run my application he crashs on:

```
import clr
```

with this error:

```
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

I have also rebuild pythonnet with Visual C# 2010 express, with x86 platform, but nothing.

Can anyone help me, please.
And possibly can anyone tell me the required .NET Framework installed for use pythonnet.

Comment: did you follow installation instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25091750/2230844?

Comment: Tank you very much Yole. I solved following this post that you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this behavior too. I fixed it by installing Python.net via pip:

`python -m pip install pythonnet` (might need to run as Administrator/root)

After installation completes you should not get any error when executing

```
> python
> import clr
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because of that your `clr.pyd` cannot find the `Python.Runtime.dll`. Basically You have already import the `clr.pyd` successfully, but Your the `clr.pyd` cannot find the `Python.runtime.dll`. So in order to make your dll searchable, you need to add the location of your `Python.Runtime.dll` into the `System PATH`.

Let's say you have your `main.py` which `import clr` and your `clr.pyd` and `Python.Runtime.dll` in the same directory, you will just need to add the below few lines at the beginning of your `main.py`:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./')) # add the current file location to sys path so that the clr module is searchable
```